# Move Android app resources to external memory

Tags: android, sd-card

I'll keep it short - I've got a directory with a bunch of files inside it that my app requires. I need to move these to the SD card, because it's pointless keeping it on internal memory. How do I go about this?

I'm assuming I'll need to keep the directory in res, initially, then open/create the required folder on external memory, and move all the files there.

How do I do this only *once*? Do I have to check the integrity of the external folder every time I run my app?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same requirement now, and I think APK Expansion Files are the better solution.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 2):

You can easily iterate over each of your res/ folders and, if you wish, copy them to SDCARD.
An example for the res/raw folder:

```
void iterate_over_res_raw() {
    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        String rawElement = fields[count].getName();
    }
}
```

And from there copy selected resources to SDCARD.

But this will not solve your problem because **you will not be able to delete the res files after copying them.** An app may never delete or update its own APK's content. It's a security restriction.

So what can you do:

**A.** Create an apk with no/minimal resource files and have it download the additional resources from your server and into the SDCARD upon first run.

**B.** Allow installation of entire APK onto the sdcard by setting installLocation to preferExternal:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          .......
          android:installLocation="preferExternal" >
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using res folder, res folder is designed to be maintained within the apk file.

To make sure your files are saved separated to your app you will need to do it by yourself, downloading your resources after app is installed and saving it where you want, but afterwards you will need to check for integrity and load by yourself as well.

Comment: Download it from where, though? Is there no way to somehow bundle the files in with the APK, then move them to the SD card?

Comment: You will need a server for it.